# Share data between two UIWindows

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, uiwindow, airplay, uiscreen

My objective is to have an AirPlay option for my iOS app that shows the same content as the iPad (like a mirror) except slightly modified to the 16x9 aspect ratio of the TV.

I have all the initial setup complete, up to the point where I have the second window and the opportunity to set its root view controller.

My current strategy is to create two separate view controllers, one for iPad, one for TV, then create some channel for them to communicate through.

Is this the most efficient way to solve this problem? Is there a better way, perhaps that involves me using the same view controller but with different `UIView`s?

Comment: Why not use the same view controller but with auto layout and probably size classes (I’m not very familiar with them, so not sure if  they are good option)

Comment: If I do that, one window goes black. Is there a way to show both windows at the same time?

Comment: Of course, didn’t thought of that. A view controller can only be shown within one window at the same time. – If you follow the MVC pattern there should be no problem in creating two instances. Why do they need to communicate?

Comment: If I have two instances, then they have two different sets of properties correct? So any actions taken on one won't be reflected on the other.

Comment: What type of actions are you trying to mirror? UIElements? Drawings?

Comment: Yeah, I need to change UIElement positioning, transparencies, animations, etc. In addition to unseen properties such as some int and float values.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/80914/discussion-between-jaun7707-and-idmean).